# command line "| was unexpected at this time." message

Tags: command-line

Just wondering why I get the "| was unexpected at this time." message when I run the following:

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims==; " %%a in (' (wmic process call create "%exec%","%workdir%") ^| find "test" ') do set test=%%a
```

but no error when I run the following:

```
 (wmic process call create "%exec%","%workdir%") ^| find "test"
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are more characters to be [escaped](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html) in parsed command:

```
                     (wmic process call create "%exec%","%workdir%") | find "test"
rem  need to escape: ↑                                 ↑           ↑ ↑
```

Next command should work - albeit there is no ´test´ word to find in `wmic` output, probably:

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims==; " %%a in (' ^(wmic process call create "%exec%"^,"%workdir%"^) ^| find "test" ') do set test=%%a
rem  properly escaped:                 ↑                                  ↑            ↑  ↑
```

Tested using

```
(wmic process call create "cmd.exe","%temp%") | find "ProcessId"
```

Then, next commands sets process ID of created `cmd` to variable `test`:

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims==; " %%a in (' ^(wmic process call create "cmd.exe"^,"%temp%"^) ^| find "ProcessId" ') do set test=%%a
```